# Can't use session variable in routes.php file in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am use following code to retrieve the session variable in routes.php

```
if($this->db_session->userdata('request_url')!="")
{
$route['user/(:any)'] = "search_user_name/redirect_url/".$_SESSION['request_url'];
$this->db_session->unset_userdata('request_url');
}
else {
    $route['user/(:any)'] = "search_user_name/index/$1";
}
```

the session variable would be set into template/header.php

```
$this->db_session->set_userdata('request_url', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use db_session in routes.php because routes.php is parsed before db_session is loaded.
Maybe you should create a base controller and redirect from the constructor of the base controller.

Comment: can i add this in `ci_controller` ?

Comment: I think it should work. I didn't use codeigniter for ages though

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if iam wrong.
You can use hooks.
[Codeigniter user guide hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use database in routes and put your routes url in database.
Here is an example:

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$table2 =  $db->dbprefix.'lang';
$query2 = $db->get( $table2 );
$result2 = $query2->result();
foreach( $result2 as $row )
{   
    $fields = $db->list_fields($table2);
    $findme   = 'code';
    foreach($fields as $field):
        $pos = strpos($field, $findme);
        if($pos !== false and $row->$field != ''):
            $route[''.$row->$field.''] = 'main/setlang/$1';
        endif;
    endforeach;
}
```